# Opening a SharePoint document in a new window from an SSRS report

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report where I am trying to give the user the ability to go directly to a SharePoint document by clicking on a field in my report.  The source data for the report is an SQL table, and one of the fields in that table has the full url.  If I select the Go To URL option and provide this field as the URL, it successfully opens the document, however, it does it in the same window.  If you click back to return to the report, the report is no longer displayed.  Therefore, I'd like to have it open in a new window.  I've viewed a bunch of the solutions posted here on stackoverflow, but it seems like none of them are passing the full url via a fieldname.

I tried this
="javascript:void(window.open('Fields!SignedDocument.Value'))"
but it tries to go to this non-existent url:
https://reportserver.abc.org/Reports/Fields!SignedDocument.Value

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is adding your field as part of the text.

You want the expression to insert your value into the OPEN string. Use the double quote to close the string, then add your field value and append the rest of the string (easier done than said).

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" & Fields!SignedDocument.Value & "'))" .
```

This will put whatever the value of the Signed Document field into the string.